# Godot 4's MultiMesh doesn't display the correct colors

Tags: rendering, mesh, godot, gdscript, godot4

I tried following Godot's documentation on [MultiMeshes](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_multimesh.html) (the set_instance_color is specially interesting), but my models always end up washed out, way brighter than they should be (left is the correct model, right is after multimeshes applied):

[image]

It's a model made out of voxels. Each cube is put into the same multimesh and then each instance's color is changed depending on the imported model's colors.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by setting `vertex_color_is_srgb` to `true` in my [material](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_basematerial3d.html).